# Error while executing command through java code

Tags: java, command

I am trying to install postgreSql.exe through java code. I have kept installer exe file under `workspace/project-root-folder/data`. I am trying to execute below command through my java code:

```
installationCommand = "postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows-x64.exe --mode unattended --installer-language en --serverport 5433 --superaccount test_admin --superpassword  ‘password’"
```

Below is the code snippet which I am using in my java code :

```
System.out.println("Lets install postgreSql");
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder();
b.directory(new File("data").getAbsoluteFile());
b.command(installationCommand);
b.start();
```

With this set up I am getting below **exception**:

```
   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows-x64.exe --mode unattended --installer-language en --serverport 5433 --superaccount protoel_admin --superpassword  ‘password’" (in directory "C:\DurgeshProjectWork\Workspace\protoel-core\data"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at frontend.guifx.pginstallation.PgStandaloneInstaller.installPg(PgStandaloneInstaller.java:27)
    at frontend.guifx.controller.ProtoelController.initialize(ProtoelController.java:386)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at frontend.guifx.main.ProToelApplication.start(ProToelApplication.java:34)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/953109155.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/2034688500.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/3243045.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1007251739.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1508395126.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 25 more
```

Could anybody please let me know how to execute the command from specific directory through java code. Kindly help in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're specifying wrong directory in `.directory()` method. You have to double check that. Make sure that the value passed to this method  points to the postgresql installer directory.

Comment: the value in directory function is coming as expected. it is showing the directory till my data folder. But still throwing the exception above

Answer (score 0):

To use this command, you have to split every argument into an array of Strings. See [`ProcessBuilder.command(String... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command(java.lang.String...)) documentation. You could use `installationCommand.split(" ")` to get an `String[]`.

Also check if the directory path is correctly, just in case.